# Asp XML Parsing Error: no root element found Location

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-core

I have the following jQuery/Ajax to be triggered on button clicked, on btn select click passs the selected radio button value to controller action and open detail page. but for some reason it gives me the following error

In Mozilla  console

> XML Parsing Error: no root element found Location:
> bill/bill/Details/43661 Line Number 1,
> Column 1:

In Chrome i get

> POST bill/bill/Details/43661 405 (Method
> Not Allowed)

Comment: As the first thing, you should not use `type: 'post'` Ajax requests on a web method that is set as `[HttpGet]`. Use `type: 'get'`.

Comment: @Tomalak ok Thank you! now error is gone button button doesn't trigger anything, when i check browser console all looks good shows the right url but stays on the same page.

Comment: What do you expect that it does? Reload your page?

Comment: @Tomalak i just want to load detail page, everything is looks good but when i click the button nothing happen in the page but in browser Network tab i sends data to right page, i changed the button type to submit but no luck on that too

Comment: yep, that works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments it became clear that you actually want to load the `'/Billing/Billing/Details/<id>` view on button click.

In this case an Ajax request does not help you. It's easier to directly set the URL of the current page:

```
$('#btnSelect').click(function () {       
    var selectedId = $('.invoiceID:checked').val();
    window.location.pathname = '/Billing/Billing/Details/' + selectedId;
});
```

When you change any part of `window.location`, the browser navigates to the new URL.